# Add variable network latency at a given point in time

Tags: java, testing, networking, timeout

### What I want to do

I am testing timeout settings for some components (JavaMail, JDBC driver, etc.) in my application.

For example,  when `mail.smtp.connectiontimeout` is 1000ms and `mail.smtp.timeout` is 3000ms in JavaMail, I need the following test cases:

1. Connect takes 500ms, and read message takes 500ms
2. Connect takes 4000ms
3. Connect takes 500ms, and read takes 4000ms

Similarly, when you set `loginTimeout=1` in JDBC URL and `set statement_timeout to 3000` in PostgreSQL, I need similar test cases for PostgreSQL.

### Question

You can simulate network latency with `tc`, but It can only add fixed latency to the network. I want to add variable latency (500ms / 4000ms) to an arbitrary process (MTAs / PostgreSQL) at a given point in time (before connection / after connection).

### Question

How can I add variable network latency for an arbitrary process at a given point in time?

Comment: There are devices that do exactly that.

Comment: (1) i don't think you can assign latency to process. packets queueing can only be done based on packet content. but you should be able to differentiate packets based on IP and port numbers (aka flows). (2) if you want to assign different latencies to different "flows" you need a scheduler. You could try having tc-htb or any other listed in tc man page that allows you to assign different qdisc to different "sub-classes". (3) if the latency should vary randomly, you can set jitter. Otherwise i would try to write a script that changes netem parameters. If it is not fast enough you will probably

Comment: need to write one yourself.